# Why is a game slower (fps) when using a bigger display?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, lag, frame-rate

I'm making a game in `Swift` using `SpriteKit`. I have a `SKSpriteNode` who is running a basic action. When I run it on `Xcode` using an Iphone 4s, everything is smooth(high fps). However, when I run it on a bigger display like an Ipad, it's very slow (low fps). Here's is the basic code I use:

```
var node = SKSpiteNode()
//...
self.addChild(node)
//...
let action = SkAction.scaleBy(4, duration: 2)  
//...
node.runAction(action)
```

Any ideas why? Thanks in advance... Anton

Comment: More pixels to draw...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common phenomena but has nothing to do with the different devices, but with the simulator of Xcode.

**Don't compare the simulator-rendering with the real device-rendering.**

If your game works on your iPhone 4S, it will most likely work on any other device. The Simulator isn't as powerful as the device. In 99.9% of all cases, the performance on a real device is much better.

So if you ever want to check the performance of your game, check it on a real device. Apple allows every developer to test it on the device, without buying a developer-account.

Comment: Just tested on an Ipad and it runs as smooth as on the 4s. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's because the rendering is being done for many more pixels and it takes more graphical processing than it would on a small screen.

Comment: Would there be any way to reduce the lag?

Answer (score 0):

> However, when I run it on a bigger display like an Ipad, it's very slow (low fps).

This is not surprising. Drawing takes time, and larger screens require much more drawing than small ones.

Comment: Would there be any way to reduce the lag?